# Pass default value to useState in React

Tags: reactjs

I am having a form that passes values to a useState

I have this  `showrefid` its value is set to either `true` or `false`
I want to pass the value of inputs into `setAllValues` based on `true` or `false` of `showrefid`

if  `showrefid` is false I want to pass a default value that is already prefixed as value `sony`

```
{showrefid ? (
            <input
              name="userid"
              onChange={handleChange}
              style={styles.input}
              type="text"
              placeholder="userid"
            />
          ) : (
            <input
              name="userid"
              value="sony"
              onChange={handleChange}
              type="text"
              readonly="readonly"
             
            />
          )}
```

```
 const handleChange = (e) => {
    setAllValues({ ...allValues, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a default value to `useState` whenever the component gets rendered for the first time

```
const [allValues, setAllValues] = useState(showrefid ? { userid: "sony" } : {})
```

After that, you can set it directly to the input field

```
<input
   name="userid"
   value={allValues.userid}
   onChange={handleChange}
   type="text"
   readonly="readonly"
/>
```

If `showrefid` can be modified from other places and you want to update your state accordingly, you can call `useEffect`

```
useEffect(() => {
  if(!showrefid) {
    setAllValues({ ...allValues, userid: "sony" })
  }
}, [showrefid])
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe consider using showrefid variable inside your handleChange function?

```
const handleChange = (e) => {
  setAllValues(showrefid
    ? { ...allValues, [e.target.name]: e.target.value }
    : { /* whatever value you want to set when false */ });
 };
```